# error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Tags: c++

In my code, I am calling the function like this:

```
Simulator::Schedule (Seconds(seconds),
                     &HelloProtocol::sendScheduledInterest(seconds), this, seconds);
```

Here is the signature of the above function:

```
  /**
   * @param time the relative expiration time of the event.
   * @param mem_ptr member method pointer to invoke
   * @param obj the object on which to invoke the member method
   * @param a1 the first argument to pass to the invoked method
   * @returns an id for the scheduled event.
   */
  template <typename MEM, typename OBJ, typename T1>
  static EventId Schedule (Time const &time, MEM mem_ptr, OBJ obj, T1 a1);
```

And the definition of function sendScheduledInterest() is:

```
void
HelloProtocol::sendScheduledInterest(uint32_t seconds)
{
    //...
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
hello-protocol.cpp: In member function ‘void ns3::nlsr::HelloProtocol::scheduleInterest(uint32_t)’:
hello-protocol.cpp:58:60: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

If I remove the `&` before the function call, it gives the following error instead:

```
hello-protocol.cpp: In member function ‘void ns3::nlsr::HelloProtocol::scheduleInterest(uint32_t)’:
hello-protocol.cpp:58:75: error: invalid use of void expression
```

Comment: `HelloProtocol` is defined as `Void`, but you're trying to take the address of it.

Comment: When I remove the address of operator, it gives different error. Why is that?

Comment: Remove the `&` and you're then passing a `void ` as an argument to a function, which makes no sense. It's essentially the same error, but the compiler is spotting it at a different point in the process.

Comment: The second argument to `Schedule` is supposed to be a pointer to member function. Instead, you're invoking the member function and trying to take the address of the return value. You need `Simulator::Schedule (Seconds(seconds), &HelloProtocol::sendScheduledInterest, this, seconds);`

Comment: So I will have to change return type of this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the address of the return value of `sendScheduledInterest` instead of the address of the method itself. Remove the `(seconds)` bit.

It seems like you may be intending to bind the `seconds` value to the call to `sendScheduledInterest`

With the standard library this can be achieved like this:

change `Schedule` to

```
EventId Schedule(const Time&, std::function<void()>);
```

and then use it as

```
Schedule(Seconds(seconds), bind(&HelloProtocol::sendScheduledInterest, this, seconds));
```

Comment: Schedule function is from another library and I can not change it.

Answer (score 5):

`HelloProtocol::sendScheduledInterest` is a `void` function. That means it returns **no value**. You can neither invoke the address of operator (&) on the return value of a void function nor can you pass it as an argument to another function unless that type is also void, which could only happen if there are some templates involved.

It appears you actually intend to pass the function pointer as the argument like this:

```
Simulator::Schedule(
    Seconds(seconds),
    &HelloProtocol::sendScheduledInterest,
    this,
    seconds);
```

In both cases, the compiler is telling you exactly what the issue is.

In the first case, a void expression is **not** an lvalue. You can think of an lvalue as something that can be assigned to on the left hand side of an assignment statement. The address of operator (&) can only be applied to lvalues.

In the second case, you are trying to use a void expression where it is not allowed, namely as the argument to a function whose formal argument type is non-void.